# Drywall screws snap off when trying to fix squeaky subfloor

Tags: subfloor

I am using 1 1/2 drywall screws from the top of the floor, to stop the squeak. Using screw gun and collated screws. The gun is snapping the heads off the screws, is this OK? And will it stop the squeaking with the heads broken off? There is flooring going down afterwards, so screw head indention is not an issue.
    Thanks

Comment: I use deck screws instead for anything that isn't actually drywall. Torx or Robertson helps. You can't control screw guns very well.  When a screw bottoms hard, it must hop out or break off.  That's why I use a "speed wrench" with a "bit holder" for both speed and control.  http://amzn.to/1UP7JM2 http://amzn.to/1K1Bx7U

Comment: Drywall screws are for securing drywall to framing, they're not much good for anything else.

Answer (score 4):

It won't likely cause a problem, and it may resolve the squeak. Drywall screws are very hard and somewhat brittle to keep them from stripping during install. For that reason, they're not ideal for your current purposes.

That said, I'd consider those screws too small. You only have 3/4" remaining after you go through the subfloor (at most). Also, you won't be able to easily remove them later if you need to.

I'd use 2-1/2" construction (gold) screws from a good manufacturer (cheap screws are cheap) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Drywall screws are known for being brittle and will frequently snap. They aren't recommended for any kind of wood work or construction for this reason. You should look for a construction-grade or even better a deck-grade screw.

You could also look into a specialized system for this. Depending on what part of the floor-system is causing your squeak, a fully-threaded screw probably won't help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not endorsing a specific product, but why don't you pick up a box of cement board or "hardibacker" screws, or deck screws for that matter. It's unlikely that you'll snap the heads off, and while the broken drywall screws *might* stop the squeaking, at least for a while, I would think that a good solid screw head pinning the boards down would stand a better chance of solving the problem long-term.

I've had an extremely squeaky floor become dead silent after screwing down cement board and tiling a floor. Which, I suppose, isn't surprising. But my point is that there are screws essentially made for this purpose, and drywall screws don't really fit that description.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but cementboard scews have large heads with deep flutes and may be difficult to get flush. A good construction screw has nearly the same thread diameter with a more suitable head.